# Is it possible to edit web address without doing it manually?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, browser

How can I turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

without doing typing it manually into my address bar?
a script? a shortened url? is is even possible to do it without typing it into your address bar

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) API in JavaScript. The API allows you to change the URL by executing a Script. There are already many articles covering this topic.

Example usage:
`window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'; // Direct to google.com`

Comment: ok. what if the site wasnt mine and i cant add scripts what do i do

Comment: @KingKwame wait so are you asking if there's a magical way to change the address bar from literally doing nothing?

Comment: yea...........................

Comment: Well you could... write a chrome extension or something in that category i guess... but that wouldn't make much sense.